# Getting data from tables using parse.com and Android

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am working on parse.com with Android. I just want to get the data from different table. For example ObjectId columns etc. I have made the following code snippet but it is not giving me other values. I have pasted Image and Code snippet for better understanding.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("UserInfo");
        // query.whereEqualTo("userName",user_name);
       query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
           @Override
           public void done(List<ParseObject> categoryAttributes, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                 for (int i = 0; i < categoryAttributes.size(); i++){



                 }
                   }
                else {
                       Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                      // Alert.alertOneBtn(getActivity(),"Something went wrong!");
                   }   
           }
       });
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

these values are retrieved with ParseObject
so in your for loop, just categoryAttributes.getString("$column_name")

if your column is a Pointer, and you want it to be returned with your query.
you need to query.include("$pointer_column_name");

Answer (score -1):

I have solved my problem. Actually i was getting Parse array so i just use For Each loop to get the data from that array. Now the complete code is given below:

```
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
               @Override
               public void done(List<ParseObject> categoryAttributes, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                     for (int i = 0; i < categoryAttributes.size(); i++){
                         //categoryAttributes.equals("medicaNote");
                        for (ParseObject post : categoryAttributes) {


                        String mediNoteString  =   post.getString("mediote");

                        String kjh = post.getObjectId();

                        String medicationString  =   post.getString("medics");
                        String mediConditionsString =   post.getString("metion");
                        String bloodGroupString =   post.getString("blop");

                        String dateOfBirthString =   post.getString("daterth");

                          }
                     }
                       }
                    else {
                           Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                          // Alert.alertOneBtn(getActivity(),"Something went wrong!");
                       }   
               }
           });
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer by clicking on the green tick. This marks the problem as resolved in the SO system....